# NOT gate output question

Tags: voltage, logic-gates, output

Newbie here with a very basic circuit question. I believe I understand how the transistor portion of the NOT gate depicted below works. What I am unclear about is why the output voltage Y changes from a high voltage to a low voltage when A (Q1 input) goes from low voltage to high?

Y is connected to 5 V via R2 before Q1 and it seems that Y would stay at ~5 V, whether or not Q1 is conducting collector current to ground.

I built the circuit to read data from a low cost caliper. Caliper input is A and Y is attached to a GPIO pin on an ESP32. The circuit works and now I am trying to understand the electrical flow.

I’m sure its something simple, but I haven’t been able to wrap my head around it. Any insight would be appreciated.

[image: e]

Comment: Welcome!  Did you perhaps mean "NOT" gate, more usually known as an inverter?  A NOR gate has two or more inputs.

Comment: The transistor (Q1) can short the output to ground harder than R2 can pull it up to +5V. It acts as a switch.

Answer (score 2):

When Q1 is "off", no current flows from the collector to the emitter and that means no current flows through the resistor. By Ohm's law, the voltage on both sides of the resistor will be the same, i.e. 5V.

When Q1 is "on", current flows from the collector to the emitter and enough current flows so that the other end of the resistor is close to 0V. For example, if R2 is 10K it would take only 0.5mA of current to flow to have the other end of the R2 reach 0V (again this by Ohm's law). When Q1 is "on" it could easily allow several milliamps of current through the transistor.

Now to turn Q1 "off" we only need to bring the base close to 0V. To turn Q1 "on" we need to have some current flow through the base and raising the input A to 5V will do that with an appropriately value for resistor R1.

The circuit which was part of the original question:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It operation is simple. When  A is low (at or near 0V) the transistor passes no current so can be considered open circuit. Therefore Y is pulled up to 5V via R2.
As the voltage on A rises there comes a point where the base emitter junction (it looks like a diode from the point of view of the base) exceeds the forward voltage threshold Vbe (usually about 0.7V) and base current starts to flow. This causes much more current to flow from the collector to the emitter (Ib X hfe) through R2. It is usual to design these circuits for an excess of base current in order to drive the transistor into saturation. In this state the transistor looks close to a short circuit and the collector, Y, is near 0V.

Answer (score 0):

Your caliper produces a voltage output that is something like 0V or 1.5V.

When the voltage at A is 0V, no current flows through the base junction of Q1 and the transistor remains 'off' so R2 pulls the output Y up to the 3.3V your ESP32 requires (I am assuming you are actually using 3.3V rather than the 5V shown on the diagram).

When the voltage is 1.5V, current flows through R1, about (1.5V - 0.7V)/R1. If R2 is high enough value then the transistor will shunt the current from R2 to ground and the voltage falls to almost zero (more than good enough for your ESP32). The transistor's *raison d'être* is to take the input at the base and amplify it into a higher collector. It would like to sink 100 or 200 or 300x the base current, but it can only draw as much as 3.3V/R2 and in fact it can't get quite to 0V output.

Probably in reality we'd make R2 about 5x R1 so the output gets nice and close to 0V. That's a "forced beta" of 20 times the ratio of voltages ((1.5-0.7)/3.3)

So your caliper output signal is *voltage shifted* from 0/1.5V to 3.3V/0V and *inverted*  (high in = low out and vice versa).

Note that since the transistor draws current when the input is high, it will drain your caliper battery even faster than normal for a cheap caliper.

As a learning aid, originally in Horowitz and Hill's "Art of Electronics" here is a visual description of how a transistor works using "Transistor Man". Transistor man looks at the ammeter connected to the base current and adjusts the collector resistance to try to make the current maybe 200x the base current. The lowest transistor man can turn the rheostat is to 0Ω, at which point all the voltage drops across your R2 and none across the transistor.

[image]

Comment: you are correct, sir.  vcc is 3.3v, not 5v as in the diagram.  the circuit was originally for an arduino but i adapted to the esp32.

Comment: gotta love the "transistor man" diagram.  i also found an explanation from the perspective of the gpio port on wikipedia.  i think i'm beginning to understand it.  per wiki "This means that the GPIO pin can effectively assume three values:
    Logical 0 (connection to ground)
    Logical 1 (connection to VCC)
    High-impedance (also called “floating”, “Hi-Z”, “tri-stated”)"

Comment: sorry the post is chopped up.  when A goes high and Q1 flows from collector to emitter to ground, then the gpio port is connected to ground (logical 0).  when A is low then the gpio port is connected to Vcc via R2 (logic high) since the flow to ground through Q1 is blocked.

Comment: Yes. When the GPIO is configured as an input (without pullup or pulldown) it is very high impedance, so it has no effect on the collector voltage.